# CakePHP two forms next to each other instead of below each other

Tags: forms, cakephp

I'm developing a form in CakePHP where I want to set two forms next to each other. I'm creating it using this code.

```
echo $form->input('timeback', array('options' => array('week',1,2,3,)));
```

This code creates a dropdown, followed by this code:

```
echo $form->end('submit');
```

This all works well, except that these two forms should be next to each other instead of below each other.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 3):

You should use CSS to solve issues like this. 
Anyway try setting form tag with style "display:inline" instead of its default "display:block"

Comment: Additionally, know that the form helper automatically adds a div to surround each input/label block, unless you pass a 'div' => false array index to the form helper method.